# how to get pagecount in background object in pdfmake?

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

> how to get **pageCount** in background object, here is my code.

```
background: (currentPage, pageCount) => {
  if (currentPage === 1) {
    return [
        {
            image: img.coverbg,
            height: 521,
            width: 756
        }
    ]
  }
  else if(currentPage == pageCount) {
    return [
        {
            image: img.headbg,
            width: 755,
            height: 30,
        },
    ]
  }
},
```

i want **pageCount in background**, but i didnt get that,
i only get **currentPage**,

so how to **get pageCount in background object**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can't get **pageCount** in the background object,
>
> we have to find another way for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `header` and `footer` functions to access the `pageCount` parameter.

These functions have three parameters - `currentPage`, `pageCount` and `pageSize` and you can apply any logic and return any valid pdfmake element from these functions.

So essentially, what you're doing in `background` can be done in either `header` or `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Access current page using currentPage and total page count using pageCount

```
docDefinition = {
  pageMargins: [40, 150, 40, 40],
  header: {
      margin: 25.5,
      columns: [
          {
              image: logo,
              height: 106.4,
              width: 540
              // alignment: 'center'
          }
      ]
  },
  footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
    return [{ text: 'Page ' + currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount, alignment: 'center' }];
  },
  content: pdf, //pdf is all the data i use to generate pdf

  defaultStyle: {
    font: 'Times'
  }
}
```

Comment: i am asking for 'pageCount' in 'background' object, i only get currenctPage in that.

Comment: It's the limitation of of pdfmake